# Find a specific function in array of callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

For some kind of event handling I'm collecting callbacks in an array to call them later.
However it should also be possible to remove a specific callback function again.
The problem is when a callback was added to the array with '.bind(this)' then not the original function is added, so I have problems finding that function in my array to remove it.

I have created a jsfiddle to make things clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/x7oanaLv/

I use `var index = callbacks.indexOf(aFunction);` to get the index of the function to remove it. But if the function was added with .bind(this) the indexOf-function will return -1.

If you use the first button to add a callback to the callbacks array you can remove it again by pressing the remove button. The second button will add a bound callback with .bind(this). This can't be removed anymore because I can't find this function in the array.

How can I find a bound callback in an array if you want to remove it by passing the original function?

Comment: Instead of just pushing them anonymously in an array, why don't you use an object with keys? So the functions could be found by key.

Comment: In short, you can't. Store the bound function somewhere so that it is accessible to the remover.

Comment: sad to hear that this is not possible. i like the suggestion by Jeremy Thille. Howeve I decided to pass the original function and the context as an additional parameter to the event system instead of binding it. So the event system can call the function on the right context with .apply(context, [params]) and since it only stores original functions it can find and remove them.